# How do I combine a ShellBar with Page or DynamicPage?

Tags: sapui5

Code sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/KPLJXzI4n1L0fG4Z

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f">
  <App>
    <pages>
      <f:ShellBar />
      <PageOrDynamicPage>
        <!-- ... -->
      </PageOrDynamicPage>
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

The last row of list / responsive table is off screen.
[image: Screenshot of the sample plunk]
<sup>100th item not visible.</sup>

I have also tried adding the ShellBar as the first content of the root view element defined in App.view.xml, which results in a double vertical scroll bar.

I also tried putting a Shell around the App instead of a separate ShellBar, but the bar is not showing: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tmk6vd5CF4IEZC2y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `sap.f.ShellBar` is a bar with a fixed height. It will push the content down if the sibling (e.g. `sap.m.Page`) tries to be 100% in height. This can be avoided by adding the content to a separate `sap.m.NavContainer`.

### `sap.f.ShellBar` with `sap.m.Page`

**Sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/LkGOQJt0xd6kNVuX**

I assume you'd like to have the ShellBar always visible on top. The above sample puts the bar in the root view, so that it's always there no matter where the user navigates to.

By leveraging the `sap.m.NavContainer`, no content is off screen:

[image: Screenshot of the sample plunk]

### `sap.f.ShellBar` with `sap.f.DynamicPage`

**Sample: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.f.ShellBar/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBarWithFlexibleColumnLayout**

It utilizes `sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout`, `sap.f.DynamicPage`, and `sap.f.routing.Router` to align with the current Fiori design guidelines. Internally, FlexibleColumnLayout makes use of the `sap.m.NavContainer` too for each one of its three columns.

Comment: **PS:** there is currently an issue with `sap.m.Shell` if you're trying to apply [letterboxing](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/) to the inner container only (I.e. excluding `sap.f.ShellBar`): https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3344#issuecomment-923032320